# XamlObjectWriter and namespaces via configuration (cannot use XmlnsDefinitionAttribute)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, portable-class-library

I'm using Systeml.Xaml to create a **custom layout engine that is based on XAML**. Since it's cross-platform, the 95% of the types are defined in Portable Class Libraries, it's impossible to use the [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to "decorate" the default assemblies.

I would like to use XamlReader to read my XAML-formatted files. The problem is that my the objects belong to several namespaces. Currently, if I want the XamlReader to be able to instantiate each one, I have to specify from which namespace each object like this:

```
<Window Title="Title" xmlns="clr-namespace:Perspex.Win32;assembly=Perspex.Win32"
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Perspex;assembly=Perspex.Base">
    <Window.Content>
        <TextBlock xmlns="clr-namespace:Perspex.Controls;assembly=Perspex.Controls" Text="{r:Binding}" />    
    </Window.Content>    
</Window>
```

How can I make the XamlReader to have a set of **default namespaces** that are implicit so they are discovered without specifying namespaces?

Edit: The current code I have is this. I'm using at XamlXmlReader to do it.

```
    private static object Load(XmlReader reader)
    {          
        XamlXmlReader xamlXmlReader = new XamlXmlReader(reader, xamlSchemaContext);
        XamlObjectWriter writer = new XamlObjectWriter(
            xamlSchemaContext,
            new XamlObjectWriterSettings
            {
                XamlSetValueHandler = SetValue,                                        
            });

        while (xamlXmlReader.Read())
        {
            writer.WriteNode(xamlXmlReader);
        }

        object result = writer.Result;

        return result;
    }
```

As you can see, I tried with a XamlSchemaContext with some of the default assemblies, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: How about using the [XamlReader.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590393(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes a ParserContext argument, which has a [XmlnsDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.parsercontext.xmlnsdictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say: I'm using a XamlXmlReader. Look at the edited question. I will post the current code I have. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Clemens it seems that it worked like that in the past. XmlnsDictionary is a part of the ParserContext that is no longer applicable for .NET 4.0 and newer. Objects like XamlObjectWriter receive a XamlSchemaContext :( Unfortunately, thd docs don't tell much about it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the assembly level XmlnsDefinitionAttribute? It allows you to define one xmlns that maps to several CLR namespaces in one or more assemblies.
Thanks, Rob

Comment: Unfortunately, the elements that we require to be "inflated" (read) are defined in Portable Class Libraries. We cannot use the attribute since it's not part of the the .NET subset for PCLs :(